# Conditional show text block in .docx using OpenTBS based on variable value

Tags: docx, opentbs, tinybutstrong

In my project I use TinyButStrong / OpenTBS to generate Word documents from templates. First I load a variable like `myuser` in the document.

```
[onload;tplvars;myuser=user]
```

The document is provided with the required variables, so I can add tags like this where the name is placed on the variable:

```
Hello [myuser.firstName]!
```

Also conditional values work fine:

```
[onshow;block=tbs:p;when [myuser.firstName]='John'] This is a paragraph just for John.
```

But when I have multiple paragraphs that I want to show/hide, it's not easy to select the correct paragraphs (or change the template and add a paragraph). Is it possible to create blocks that have a 'begin' and 'end' that are shown based on a value? Something like this (pseudocode):

```
Paragraph 1
[if [myuser.firstName] = 'John']
    (insert random number of paragraphs and maybe tables/other stuff here)
[end if]
Paragraph n
```

I could not find any of this in the TBS/OpenTBS docs. Does someone know a method to do this?

Thanks!

Niels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TBS has a block syntax [onshow;block=being]...[onshow;block=end] but it's a bad practice with OpenTBS because in fact in the inner XML those two tags are placed in a two separated `<w:p>` entities. So those entities will be split in two and it's a luck if they match with the newly merged contents.

One solution is to protect the begin/end tags with a paragraph entity.

```
[onshow;block=begin;enlarge=tbs:p;when ....] This paragraph will be deleted
Some text here.
Some text there.
[onshow;block=end;enlarge=tbs:p] This paragraph will be deleted
```

Another solution is to define a block on several paragraphs:
This block is defined on 3 paragraphs:

```
[onshow;block=tbs:p+tbs:p+tbs:p;when ...] Paragraph 1 - inside the block
Paragraph 2 - inside  the block
Paragraph 3 - inside  the block
Paragraph 4 - outside the block
```

The other solution is

Comment: Thanks for your response, that helped a lot!

For people that have the same question: the [onshow;block=begin ...] stuff should be in a separate paragraph since the entire paragraph is deleted.

Comment: @nielsr how do you avoid that behavior? 

I have a text like: some text, "sometimes this text, " some other text
Where I only sometimes want to show "sometimes this text,"